# Generate Junit test with cxf-codegen-plugin

Tags: java, maven, cxf

I'm using the `cxf-codegen-plugin` to generate some Java classes from a WSDL. The thing works great but the webservice is growing so I have to code more and more Junit test. I wonder if there is a way to generate Junit tests (or at least templates) with this plugin.

I have checked the documentation in http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html and found nothing. I'm open to any suggestion.

Thanks!